# Как сделать динамическое меню?

Tags: python, django

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: необходимо сделать меню, которое можно было бы редактировать из админки, и чтобы просто в шаблон вставлялось, например

```
{{ menu }}
```

Как реализовать это так, чтобы не приходилось вставлять в каждый вид код, генерирующий и возвращающий это меню?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Напишите свой [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Answer (score 0):

Вариантов масса. Вот один - treemenus, попробуй, просто и понятно ...
pip install treemenus + читаем инструкцию